# EntityFramework force globally reload before each query

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a **`DBEntities.edmx`** from my Database. In one of my Classes I use:

```
DBEntities _db = new DBEntities()
```

Now is my Problem, that after a query the EF caches the solution and if one value in the Database changes the **`.edmx`** uses the cached old value.

I found two workarounds:

1.: `_db.tbl_user.AsNoTracking().Where(x=>x.ID == _ID)`

2.: recreate the DBEntities: `_db = new DBEntities()`

but I want to know if there is a possibility to force globally, that the EF update the DBEntities if the values had changed

Comment: Use new context for each request

Comment: are you keeping one `_db` variable and using it all the time? then don't. `Dispose` it (preferably with a using statement) and create a new instance of your `DbContext` each time.

Comment: The data context is not designed to be long-lived. Reusing it over multiple operations is a mistake in your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are you keeping one _db variable and using it all the time? then
>   don't. Dispose it (preferably with a using statement) and create a new
>   instance of your DbContext each time.
>
> The data context is not designed to be long-lived. Reusing it over multiple operations is a mistake in your design

To solve the problem the using statement is needed:

```
using(DBEntities _db = new DBEntities())
{
    /* Your DB access here */
}
```

You can find a full description on [Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects?](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)