# Entity Framework: Counting the number of elements in Collection<T> (performance)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a collection property in my code-first model:

```
public class Advertisment
{
//...
  public  ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

where Comment is other model-class represents the comment of the  advertisment.
My task is obvious. The program have to count the number of comments.
There are two way:

1. through additional Int32-field:

   ```
   public ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set; }
   public int NumberOfComments;
   public void IncrementComments() // call after client leave a comment
   {
   NumberOfComments++;
   } 
   public int SumComments() //so, just return the field
   {
   return NumberOfComments;
   }
   ```
2. through calling the Count method

   ```
   public int SumComments()
   {
   return db.Comments.Where(c => c.Advertisment == this).Count(); //where db is instance of DbContext
   }
   ```

   My question about performance. The second way can appear more easy for developing, however, in this case, Entity Framework does make some request for counting elements in DB. Does it have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: Comments.Count doesn't call the entity context. It will only count the instances in your local list. Lets say your entity context is namned db, then db.Comments.Count will make a request on the context.

Comment: @Marcus H, I have edited, thank

Answer (score 3):

`db.Comments.Count()` **can** make a DB request, if you haven't queried the data since you initialized your DB-Context.
If you had queried the data, EF will count the data of your local instance.

So you have 2 possibilities:

1. You had already queried the data:
   So EF only uses the [`count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of an `IEnumerable` element
2. You have not queried the data:
   EF will query the data and than use the [`count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method as in `1.`

=> EF only will query the data if needed.

=> I don't see any downsides by using `db.Comments.Count();`

---

**Edit:**

The same is happening, when you're using `Linq` expressions on the table as in:

```
db.Comments.Where(c => c.Advertisment == this).Count();
```

But the `Linq` filter has to be applied every time you're using this line, but only on the local instance of your Database.

---

**Q:** in my scenario I only need the number of the comments, i.e. EF don't query Collection navigation property (not eager loading). I think for my situation it would be better to use only single field (int NumberOfComments) than EF would query additional data for counting. Am I wrong?

**A:** If you have only one Server instance running, you're right, but if there will be multiple instances, you get an inconsistency of data. EF context objects aren't designed to be long lived objects see the comment on this post:

[EntityFramework force globally reload before each query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024465/entityframework-force-globally-reload-before-each-query)

> The data context is not designed to be long-lived. Reusing it over multiple operations is a mistake in your design. (spender)

I.e.: you have two server running the same application in terms of Load-Balancing. If a comment would sent to one server, how should the other server increment the comment flag without counting the comments?